# How to change the storage pool size in Centos with Kvm-Qemu?

Tags: centos, qemu, storage

I have 1 Tb hard disk and Centos 7 and Kvm-Qemu have been installed.
Now I have created a vm of 4gb ram, 40 Gb disk space. The VM came up.
Now one more VM am trying to create with same 4gb ram and 40gb disk space. But it throws error saying that "less space". Only 10 GB is available

```
root@localhost ~]# df -h /var/lib/libvirt/images  
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   20G   31G  39% /  
[root@localhost ~]#<
```

Here how to change the size of the `/var/lib/libvirt/images` from 50GB to some other value?

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk  
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
sda               8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot  
└─sda2            8:2    0 930.5G  0 part   
   ├─centos-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /  
   ├─centos-swap 253:1    0  31.4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]  
  └─centos-home 253:2    0 849.1G  0 lvm  /home
sr0              11:0    1   4.2G  0 rom  /run/media/infinite/CentOS 7 x86_64  
[root@localhost ~]#       
[root@localhost ~]#       
[root@localhost ~]# df -h     
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on     
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   20G   31G  40% /     
devtmpfs                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev     
tmpfs                     32G   49M   32G   1% /dev/shm        
tmpfs                     32G   18M   32G   1% /run     
tmpfs                     32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup     
/dev/sda1               1014M  218M  797M  22% /boot    
/dev/mapper/centos-home  849G  292M  849G   1% /home    
tmpfs                    6.3G   48K  6.3G   1% /run/user/1000    
/dev/sr0                 4.3G  4.3G     0 100% /run/media/infinite/CentOS 7 x86_64      
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Look at lvextend and resize2fs (depending on your file system type)

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you do not have a separate storage volume for `/var/lib/libvirt/images`. Notice the size of your `centos-root` volume is only `31G`, but you `centos-home` is `849.1G`.If you want to increase the size of `/var/lib/libvirt/images` you will need to free up volume group space by reducing the size of `centos-home` and then create a logical volume for `/var/lib/libvirt/images`.

Like mentioned by [Raman Sailopal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/244045/raman-sailopal), look into resize2fs for reducing your `centos-home` volume to free up more space.

Alternatively, you could store your VMs under `/home` (I wouldn't do that though)